# Using recursion to make a pattern of stars and stripes

Tags: java

```
void printPattern(int n)
```

Instructions: print a pattern of n+1 lines ( 0 to n ):
line i (i = 0 to n) has i stars ("*"), followed by (n-i) stripes ("-")
For example, printPattern(3) prints:

```
---
*--
**-
***
```

I think I'll need to use a helper method to do this, but I'm new to recursion and having trouble finding a way to do this. Does anyone have any attempts?

I was using this as my helper method. I was getting a stack overflow error, and I also couldn't print any -'s

```
private void printPattern(int stars, int stripes) {

if (stars == 1) {
    stars--;
    System.out.println("*");
}
else if (stars > 1) {
    stars--;
    System.out.println("*");
}
if (stripes == 1) {
    stripes--;
    System.out.println("-");
}
else if (stripes > 1) {
    stripes -= 1;
    System.out.println("-");
}
printPattern(stars,stripes);
```

Comment: You'll never get out from that method.

Comment: What if you only used one variable `n`, as mentioned in the question, and counted the number of stars, and printed `n` asterisks "stars" and then `?` hyphens "stripes"?

Answer (score 1):

Is it needed to be a recursion solution?

In case it isn't, I give you an example of how you could do it only using for loops.

```
void printPattern(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
        int stripes = n - i;
        int stars = i;

        StringBuilder accumulator = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < stars; j++) {
            accumulator.append("*");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < stripes; j++) {
            accumulator.append("-");
        }

        System.out.println(accumulator.toString());
    }
}
```

You could improve this code by using an auxiliar method to get the string of stars-stripes instead of repeat the loop with a method signature like this: `generateSymbolString(int repeatCount, String symbol)`

I have tried use recursion with the interface `void printPattern(int n)` but I didn't get a good answer to resolve this.

Anyways, your problem with the Stack Overflow error is because you didn't define a base case in your method so the method generates infinite self calls.
To solve the stack overflow error you could do this:

```
private static void printPattern(int stars, int stripes) {
    if (stars == 1) {
        stars--;
        System.out.println("*");
    } else if (stars > 1) {
        stars--;
        System.out.println("*");
    }
    if (stripes == 1) {
        stripes--;
        System.out.println("-");
    } else if (stripes > 1) {
        stripes -= 1;
        System.out.println("-");
    }

    //base case to exit recursion because is the last print
    if (stripes != 0) {
        printPattern(stars, stripes);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to create a `void printPattern(int)`. It only accepts one integer.

Assuming this variable is named `n` like shown above, you can, in your method print `n` asterisks. *

Next, you can print `limit-n` hyphens. -

After that, you need to check if you've gone too far with `n`. If not, activate the void with `n+1`.

Comment: This is the bare minimum someone might need to understand.